# epsilon characterisation limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Hi there I have a question that I wanted to check I have done correctly I have a sequence $A_n=\sqrt3+ \frac2{n^2+\sqrt5}$

the question reads "Prove that this sequence has a limit when $n\to\infty$ and find the limit. Justify your answer by using the $\epsilon$-characterisation of a limit.

This is what I did: I wrote from inspections $\sqrt3$ remains fixed as $n\to\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac2{n^2+\sqrt5}=0$ from inspection, hence the limit of the sequence is $\sqrt3$.

I justify this by $|A_n-\sqrt3|<2/n^2$ for $n>1$ if $2/n^2<\epsilon$ then $|A_n-\sqrt3|<\epsilon$ such that $2/\epsilon<n^2$ and  $\sqrt{2/\epsilon}<n$.

By Archimedean property there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ with $N>\sqrt{2/\epsilon}$ for $n\ge N$.

We get $n\ge N>\sqrt{2/\epsilon}$ hence $|A_n-\sqrt3|<\sqrt{2/n}<\epsilon$ and $A_n$ is convergent to the limit.

Id really really appreciate if somebody could check over this and maybe improve the syntax or little errors.

Comment: your argument is not complete, when $n\ge N$ then what happens to $|A_n-\sqrt{3}|$?

Comment: n≥N which gives n≥N>(sqrt(2/ε)  ---> (2/n^2)<ε  Im not sure where Im going wrong

Comment: @James it's easier with $\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take $\epsilon>0$.

we look for $N$ such that

for $n\geq N$

$|\frac{2}{n^2+\sqrt{5}}|<\epsilon$.

as we have

$|\frac{2}{n^2+\sqrt{5}}|\leq \frac{2}{n}$.

we will look for $N$ such that

for $n\geq N$
we have  $\frac{2}{n}<\epsilon$

or

$n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$

so we can take

$N=\lfloor \frac{2}{\epsilon} \rfloor+1$.